# Yii not creating records after adding new columns

Tags: php, yii

In my web application's database I have a model named "ProducerOffer".After I generated the model using Gii I created two more columns named "booked_qty" and "available_qty".
When   I create new records its just rendering the from with empty values of attributes

My code for model

```
return array(
            array(' vegetable_id, offered_qty, unit_cost, unit_delivery_cost', 'required'),
            array(' offered_qty,  unit_delivery_cost, booking_status, booked_by, available_days', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('user_id', 'length', 'max'=>11),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id,userName,user_id, vegetable_id, offered_qty,booked_qty,available_qty, unit_cost, unit_delivery_cost,  offered_date,  booking_status, booked_by, available_days', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
             array('booked_qty,available_qty',  'safe'),
        );
```

My Code for the form

```
div style='padding-left:50px'>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array('id'=>'producer-offer-form','enableAjaxValidation'=>false,)); ?>
<p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<?php
if(Yii::app()->user->type=="PRODUCER"){

 echo $form->errorSummary($model); 
 echo $form->dropDownList($model,'vegetable_id', CHtml::listData(Vegetable::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('prompt'=>'Select Vegetable')); 
 echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'booked_quantity',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64)); 
 echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'available_quantity',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64)); 
 echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'unit_delivery_cost',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64)); 
}
if(Yii::app()->user->type==="CONSUMER"){
echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'offered_qty',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>64));

}
?>
<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',)); ?>  
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'reset', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=> 'Reset')); ?>
   <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'link', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=> 'Cancel','url'=>Yii::app()->user->returnUrl,)); ?>

</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: There are no "booked_qty" and "available_qty" attributes in your view. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you re run the CRUD generator or just the model generator?

Comment: No  I  edited the question ,I added those columns in the form .I just added the columns , I did not use gii after adding the columns.I just added the columns in the database table.

Answer (score 1):

> No I edited the question ,I added those columns in the form .I just added the columns , I did not use gii after adding the columns.I just added the columns in the database table.

Sounds to me from the comment that you need to re-run `Gii Model Generator` and also some of the `CRUD Generator` files, Running Gii model creator will make sure that your models have all the information about your table structures and how they relate to other tables. The CRUD generator will help make sure input fields are created for all table columns also.

Comment: is it possible to update the table directly using  Yii migrations? just was thinking it is a substandard way if i have regenerate every time i add a column?

Comment: I tried creating a new table using gii but same error I am getting.Its  not assigning the attributes at all . it just outputs the name of attribute and says it can't be blank. can you please help me?

Comment: Yes you can use migrations. Also an extension called Giix, it creates base models that you can regenerate when the schema changes. Meaning it creates all the attributes and relations, then your actual models extend this base model. You will need to show more about your columns in the table, what is in your model fully and what your form is too highlighting where the problem is.